# GKE update SSL certificate from Google-managed to self-managed

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to update the certificate of the Load balancer in GKE from Google-managed to self-managed.

I was following up on this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) to create Google-managed certificates, but I didn't find any docs for creating self-managed certificates. I am not sure how to do this. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-managed SSL certificates are certificates that you obtain, provision, and renew yourself. You can use this resource to secure communication between clients and your load balancer.

Make sure that you have the domain names that you want to use for your self-managed SSL certificate. If you're using Google Domains, see Step 1: [Register a domain name using Google Domains](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial#register-domain).

Step 1: Create a private key and certificate

Step 2: Create a self-managed SSL certificate resource

Step 3: Associate an SSL certificate with a target proxy

Step 4: Update the DNS A and AAAA records to point to the load balancer's IP
address

Step 5: Test with OpenSSL

After the [certificate and domain statuses are active](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#certificate-resource-status), it can take up to 30 minutes for your load balancer to begin using your self-managed SSL certificate.

For detailed information follow [Use self-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#create-key-and-cert).

Comment: Does the ingress of GKE use those steps for updating the self-managed certificate?

Comment: For nginx follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl#creating_certificates_and_keys)